# jquery ajax call to run C# code behind method in asp.net

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to call ASP.NET C# Code behind method from html javascript using ajax method.

jQuery ajax call does not respond. It does not show anything, no error message or no thing. I also tried with CDN url reference of jQuery api.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
   <script src="jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>




    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#btn1').click(function (e) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'WebForm2.aspx/TestMethod',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert('Success : ' + data.d);
                    },
                    failure: function (AjaxResponse) {
                        alert('Failed: ' + AjaxResponse.d);
                    }
                });
            });

        });

    </script>

        <input id="btn1" type="button" value="Show Method Output" />
</body>
</html>
```

//********* Code Behind method

```
namespace AjaxCallProject
{
    public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        [System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
        public static string TestMethod()
        {
             return "Result from code behind method";
        }

    }
}
```

It should display "Result from code behind method". It would be appreciated if any one show me where I made mistake, Thanks

Comment: try changing  dataType: "text",  or just getting rid of it and let jquery figure it out. right now you have it set to json but you are returning text

Comment: Anything notable in the console log?